# global name 'test' is not defined

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a two files .py File A and B,

File A using methods from file B and file B using methods from file A

file A

```
from file_b import *

def abc():
# something
   cba()
```

file B

```
from file_a import *

def cba():
# something
   abc()
```

if i trying run script for file A, i get Error

> global name 'cba' is not defined

If i change my imports to :

```
import file_a
```

and

```
file_a.abc()
```

My script works properly

It is possibility to use from file_a import * ?

Did I do something wrong?

Comment: you have a circular dependency there

Comment: All of File A is in File B, so importing B back into A it is also trying to import itself- I've put an example below that may- I hope- explain it better with an example.

Answer (score 1):

I have 3 files for a Python PyGame.

1. settings.py
2. sprites.py
3. game.py

In settings I have my global variables and some other useful constants. 
If I import my settings into my sprites file using

```
from settings import *
```

then in my main file, game.py, I just import my sprites.
If I use

```
from sprites import *
```

then I am setting the sprites AND the content of my settings file ALSO.
If I were to say

```
from sprites import player
from sprites import enemy
```

then I would NOT be getting the content of settings, even though they are imported into that NameSpace... or file.  If I want access to the tuples representing colours in my game.py file, I have to import them.

I hope this clears up the problem you are having or gives a better idea of why this is happening, as mentioned in the first comment- it is a circular reference.